# Multi sql statement with in

Tags: sql

I am using this SQL statement:

```
update users set admin=false 
where Gender='"+Gender+"' and id IN (select ID 
                                     FROM (select id 
                                           from users 
                                           ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 10) tmp)
```

can somone explain to me how does this work?
what is the "tmp" in the end?

Comment: `tmp` is an alias here, just a name for the select statement before the closing bracked; it can (but does not need to) be preceded by `AS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tmp` serves as an alias for this statement:

```
select ID FROM (select id from users ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 10) tmp
```

In this case it is not necessary. The query would work without using the alias `tmp`.

You often see these aliases used when joining tables, since they can help shorten SQL statements.

```
select a.ID, b.ANOTHER_COLUMN, b.ANOTHER_COLUMN
from SOME_LONG_TABLE_NAME a
join SOME_OTHER_LONG_TABLE_NAME b
on a.ID = b.ID;
```

Notice how the statement does not prefix the full table name when specifying the columns for selection, instead it uses the aliases `a` and `b`. Also, notice how the join also uses the aliases in the `ON` clause.  The alias allow us to assign an an identifier to refer to a table, which eliminates the burden of explicitly referring to columns and tables.

Answer (score 0):

The query is unnecessarily complicated. It's equal to:

```
update users set admin = false 
where gender='"+Gender+"' 
and id in (select id from users order by id asc limit 0, 10);
```

The statement takes the 10 highest user ids and checks wether the gender is '"+Gender+"'. If so, the record's admin column gets set to false.

Comment: It doesnt.... When i use this one i get this erroe: "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery"

Comment: So the subquery that does nothing is just a workaround to make MySQL blind as to what's happening. Queer. Well, however: the query *should* look like mine, but MySQL restrictions make you write the clumsy additional subquery level. The answer remains the same.